# Which one is correct? Watching soccer games make/makes me happy

Tags: verbs, subjects, agreement

"Watching soccer games" is the subject but the teacher argues that it is the word"watching"

Comment: The “makes” version gives you a full sentence. The “make” version leaves “watching” dangling.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the teacher is right. The 
[gerund phrase](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/gerund-phrase/) *watching soccer games* acts as the subject, and *watching* is the head word (a verbal noun). It is considered to be singular (uncountable), and it takes a singular verb (makes). The correct sentence is:

*Watching soccer games makes me happy*.

*Soccer games* is the object constituent of the gerund within the phrase.